# What did Colbert mean by “bedude form"?

Tags: orthography, prefixes, neologisms, malapropisms

In his most recent monologue on *The Late Show*, the comedian host Stephen Colbert, gently mocked a New York Times reporter's style of writing (watch the [excerpt](https://youtu.be/uJcaEs6HMls?t=586) on YouTube)

> “500 words” she whispered, her silken robe sliding to the floor as the morning sun hit her bedude form.

I think that's how the word "bedude" is supposed to be spelled, if word it is. I looked and searched online and found nothing. It's my guess that Colbert misspoke, and I would normally shrug it off; however,  seconds later he repeated the term *bedude* [?], quite emphatically I may add. Saying

> Even (This is getting sexy, this is kinda getting sexy. I like “bedude”). Even people at the White House don't know what to do, there is no war room…

Mr Colbert is an educated man, a fine wit and appears to be extremely well-read, on more than one occasion he has cited poetry and literary passages by heart, so maybe I am wrong and maybe *bedude* is a "word".

I have checked online but unearthed nothing of value. So, *bedude* could be an inside joke, a malapropism,  a spoonerism for *denude*, it could be that I have misspelt it, or it might be none of the above.

Comment: @choster Ohhhhhh... that makes sense. Please post an answer, so I can accept it!

Comment: While bedewed is certainly right here, it feels like "bedude" could be used to make fun of the recent lexical popularity of "bespoke."

Comment: @choster I hope they're analogous droplets because if she's got literal dew on her she's cold - dead cold. Maybe she's too delicate to sweat.

Comment: Choster may well be working or sleeping and deserves any rep from an answer. That would be enough to stop me taking their guys and turning it into an answer

Comment: @ChrisH  I replied almost instantaneously, and checked an hour or two later to see if he was online, he was.  Choster, for whatever reason, didn't feel like posting it as an answer. That's fine, I'm glad that Jason Bassford did, maybe a mention about the pronunciation  and its spelling would have been nice, but I'm not complaining. Upvoted and accepted.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, that seems reasonable. I just don't like to take credit when someone else got the answer, and I know I'm not alone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per a comment under the question, *bedude* is not a word. However, *bedewed* is.

From [*bedew*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bedew):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> : to wet with or as if with dew

---

We can *assume* that's the word he's pronouncing—and presumably he's describing the sun shining off of water droplets on her body. (Although, oddly, the YouTube closed-captioning used specifically ignores that single word—even when it's spoken a second time.)

Comment: Anything about the pronunciation? Is "dude" and "dewed" pronounced the same in the US because in BrEng I detect a slight difference, the former sounds  /duːd/  while the latter sounds /djuːd/.

Comment: Those are pronounced the same in the US in my experience.

Comment: According to Merriam-Webster, *dude* is pronounced `düd` also `ˈdyüd`, while *dewed* is `dü` also `ˈdyü`. (So, it's just the addition of a *d* to the present verb.)  I wouldn't think there is normally a difference.

Answer (score 1):

He may have said or meant "benuded", as in "made nude".

Comment: You can hear Colbert speaking in the YouTube link I posted. He definitely did not say "benuded"

Comment: Then it would probably be, as Choster said, bedewed.

Comment: i listened ... could not tell what word he enunciated. Someone could ask him.